# How to test if the post is in a primary category

Tags: categories

I'm trying to make a code to display a image at the end of each post, but i need to show a specific image for each post category.
I'm using the code below:

```
<?php 
    if (in_category('category1')||){
        echo '<img src="https://example.com/category1">';
    }
    elseif (in_category('category2')){
        echo '<img src="https://example.com/category2">';
    }
    elseif (in_category('category3')){

        echo '<img src="https://example.com/category3">';
    }
    elseif (in_category('category4')){
        echo '<img src="https://example.com/category4">';
    }
?>
```

It's working, but my problem now is that some posts have all the categories, and I need to test the primary category of the post.
Is there a function to do this?

Comment: There's no concept of a 'primary' category in WordPress. What do you mean by that?

Comment: As Jacob Peattie said there's no primary category in WordPress. But you can use plugin to make it. Yoast Seo has this functionality and many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you want to add an image in a specific `category` or a `post`. You can manipulate this code as you wish:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_a_image_in_post' );
function add_a_image_in_post($content){
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'post'){
        //error_log(print_r($post, true), 3, WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/debug.log');
        $all_cats = get_the_category($post);
        foreach($all_cats as $cat){
            if($cat->slug == 'sticky'){
                return $content."<img src=#1 >";
            }
        }
        //error_log(print_r($all_cats, true), 3, WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/debug.log');
        return $content."<img src=#2 >";
    }
    return $content.$content."<img src=#3 >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the categories are in the same level (for example, all of them are top-level categories), then there is no superiority. All are treated the same way.

What you can do here is to set up a hierarchical structure of your categories, and then retrieve the first category in the hierarchy. After you did the above, you can retrieve it this way:

```
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$first_category = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```